# JontJS: Hided Elements can still connect

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I hide the JointJS diagram elements by using following code

```
 rightRect.attr('./display', 'none');
```

Although they are not shown in diagram, they can still connect with link.

I used new joint.shapes.devs.Link to create link and used new joint.shapes.devs.Model to create rectangle element.

Answer (score 0):

are you still able to connect with link even after runnig this? 
    `rightRect.findView(paper).$el.hide()`